# Making a dynamic graphql call in vue/nuxt to the current route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo

I want to make a graphql call to the current route I am on. I tried to do it with the $nuxt.$route.$path but it seems I have no access to this variable in head of graphql.

Is there a way to initialize a variable and replace it with "CURRENT ROUTE" ?

My code:

```
apollo: {
    casinos: gql `query getCasino {
      casinos(where: {Slug: "CURRENT_ROUTE"}) {
        id
        Brand_Name
        Slug
        game_providers {
          id
          Provider_Name
          Provider_Logo_150x50 {
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }`
  },
```

I tried to do it with the variables() but it still does not work and I am getting a 400.

Second Try:

```
apollo: {
    casinos: gql `query getCasino ($route: String!){
      casinos(where: {Slug: $route}) {
        id
        Brand_Name
        Slug
        game_providers {
          id
          Provider_Name
          Provider_Logo_150x50 {
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }`,
    variables() {
      return {
        route: this.route
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: I know it's an old post, but care to share an answer @foka135, if any? I have a similar case and it works to me on server side with `this.$route.params.slug` instead of your `this.route` but not on the client side once the app is loaded.

Comment: Sadly I did not find any way to resolve this issue. Sorry!